# Saving the username and gender and more data when getting response from api login

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, oauth-2.0

when ever the user make login by facebook or google it return data but it does not save it in fields added to registration form like full name and gender and so on , It only save the data into the users table it save the email and username what is the problem and what should i do too please some one give me an answer

Comment: the OAuth2 module in drupal doesn't save data in the custom fields supported by another module is there any way to save the data into the custom fields

Comment: You need to map the fields explicitly. You must have a page for facebook on your Drupal site where you can map the user fields with that of facebook's

Comment: What OAuth module are you using?

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/oauth this module Clive,
Joshi Consultancy I don't understand your comment :(

Comment: Could you give us the modules you are using for the FB / Google login (OAuth, ...)? Maybe we could provide you some code to save the extra fields attached to a user ...

Comment: OAuth, OAuth connector , connector, http_client these are the module that I use

Comment: Lifting the bounty here; if you want a good answer, you really need to put some more effort into this question. There are a couple of questions in the comments that need to be addressed, and overall the clarify of this question is poor - please, spend some more time on communicating the problem you're trying to solve - it'll pay off in the long run.

Comment: @TaymoorQ. edit the question. Add more data make the idea clear .